# how can I recognize end of transfer of data in c#

Tags: c#, networking

I am writing alternative to memcached, but I discovered that c# (.net) behaves differently than c in one thing.

when I send this command using netcat:

```
echo version | nc localhost 11211
```

to c version of memcached I get a response and netcat close the connection

when I do the same to my c# version the connection remain open, because I am using this loop:

```
while (!Reader.EndOfStream && connection.Connected)
{
      ...
}
```

In that very moment the code hang on getting value from Reader.EndOfStream - this property seems to call some function which is locked to something else and waits

but clearly even if the netcat is not going to send anything else to server, c# is still "thinking" that the stream didn't really end, so netcat hang up and I need to kill it in order to close the connection. This is unwanted behaviour and I have no idea why it happens. Does anyone know how can I check the real end of stream just as the c library in memcached does it? (that means when client finish sending any data, I know it and I can close the connection)

Comment: Have you tried reversing the test (e.g. while (connection.Connected && !Reader.EndOfStream) )?  If your connection status is no longer connected, this will not call into the hanging EndOfStream test.

Comment: I am starting to think it is a bug in mono... but I didn't test it on windows as it's not that easy for me. but yes I tried it, everytime the code lock up and last call is to retrieve Reader.EndOfStream. It seems like some dead lock to me